# Create different types (3) of users in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, authentication

this is my first post here, and moreover I use google translate to communicate with you, please excuse me if I am not understandable

I am also new to programming and I am stuck on the organization of my user models, I would like to have your opinions,

I would like that when creating a user, this one has the choice between 3 categories which will display a form accordingly,

for example, when I register on the site, I can choose my status (employee, manager, client) and depending on the chosen status, the data recorded in my database will be different,

I was thinking of using a common base for all users ("email", "password") then depending on the box checked, new fields will appear as ("name", "birth", etc..) for "Client" , or (" name", "lastName", "picture", etc..) for "Employee" and another schema for "Manager"

I tried the populate function with the different schema (employee, manager, client),
is this the right direction?

a picture is worth a thousand words

[example front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZkQJ.png)

thank you for taking the time to read me, best regards

Comment: Your question is a bit open. Typically all users would be the same with an attribute "roles" there you would store the type. All the rest depends on this attribute.

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer, I was inspired in particular by this tutorial to create my 3 roles : https://www.bezkoder.com/node-js-mongodb-auth-jwt/